# PrimeNG validation with Angular2.0.0-rc.4

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I'm trying to use PrimeNG datepicker inside a ngForm and apply required validation.

```
<p-calendar formControlName="eventStartDate"  
            inputStyleClass="form-control" 
            #eventStartDate="ngModel"  
            ngControl="eventStartDate"   
            id="eventStartDate" 
            [(ngModel)]="event.eventStartDate" 
            minDate="+1d"  
            [showIcon]="true"  
            required>
            </p-calendar>  
<span [hidden]="eventStartDate.valid || eventStartDate.pristine" 
      class="help-block">
      Start Date  is required !
</span>
```

However, I'm getting an exception ,

```
Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("                    
    <div class="input-group form-inline">
    <p-calendar [ERROR ->]#eventStartDate="ngModel"  
                name="eventStartDate" 
                formControlName="eventStartDate"  
                inputStyleClass="f").
```

How should we add PrimeNG controls to angular form ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using template driven forms.

Just remove `formControlName="eventStartDate"` and replace it with `name="eventStartDate"`and I believe this should work for you.